# Loop table to update overlap date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two table, which is the source table and destination table as follow:

Original Source table:

```
ID MemberID StartDate EndDate Status
1  1        2015-02-02 2015-05-05 0
2  2        2015-02-02 2015-05-05 0
3  1        2015-03-03 2015-06-06 0
4  1        2015-04-04 2015-06-06 0
5  1        2016-01-01 2016-02-02 0
6  3        2015-01-01 2015-03-03 0
```

Original Destination table:

```
ID MemberID StartDate  EndDate
1  1        2015-03-02 2015-05-05
2  2        2015-04-02 2015-05-05
3  1        2016-01-02 2016-04-03
4  3        2015-01-01 2015-03-01
5  3        2015-03-03 2015-04-03
```

Output Source Table

```
ID MemberID StartDate  EndDate    Status
1  1        2015-02-02 2015-05-05 2(updated)
2  2        2015-02-02 2015-05-05 2(updated)
3  1        2015-03-03 2015-06-06 2(updated)
4  1        2015-04-04 2015-06-06 2(updated)
5  1        2016-01-01 2016-02-02 1(inserted)
6  3        2015-01-01 2015-03-04 3(fail)
```

Output Destination Table

```
ID MemberID StartDate  EndDate    
1  1        2015-02-02 2015-06-06
2  2        2015-02-02 2015-05-05
3  1        2016-01-02 2016-04-03
4  3        2015-01-01 2015-03-01
5  3        2015-03-03 2015-04-03    
6  1        2016-01-01 2016-02-02
```

Assumption made: Destination table date range with same memberID will never overlap. 
The pseudocode for the sql is as below. How could it be achieve?

```
foreach (var i in SourceTable)
{
  foreach(var j in DestinationTable with same memberid as i)
  {
    if (i daterange overlap with only 1 j date range)
        {
                update DestinationTable date range to new date range by taking min and max date for both src and target
                update SrcTable Status to 2
        }
        else if (i daterange overlap with more than 1 j date range)
        {
               update SrcTable Status to 3
        }
        else if (i do no overlap with any date range in j)
        {
               insert i to destination table
               update SrcTable Status to 1
        }
  }
```

Comment: Why does the `startdate` for id=1 change? And the ranges in your example destination table still overlap (id=1 overlaps with id=2, and id=2 overlaps with id=3)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have updated the post. What do you mean by startdate for id = 1 change?

Comment: In the first example id=1 has `startdate=2015-02-02` but in the second example it has a different startdate (`2015-03-02`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i see. The Destination table is a table which consist of existing date range of the member and the source table date range is new value that is required to be process. So, both of them is of different value. The value in the source table will be updated/inserted to the destination table based on condition stated as above. Hope this explanation would be clear.

Comment: adding a desired output example can make this more clear..

Comment: @JoseTuttu has added desired output.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added desired output in the post for more clarity

Comment: You state "Destination table date range with same memberID will never overlap.", yet your Output Destination Table appears to have overlapping ranges for `MemberID` 1 in rows 3 and 6. Explanation?

Comment: Trying to puzzle out Output Source Table row 5 which is "(inserted)". Doesn't the date range overlap Original Destination Table row 3?